# How can I reach body tag or another tag from Razor Page in Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, webassembly, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to reach to body from a Razor page. I have just started to learn Blazor. So I don't know if it is possible or not. Basically I'm trying to change the body class from the C# side and from different pages. I can do it with JavaScript but I want to do it with Blazor WebAssembly. It can work if the body is inside of the Razor page. But I don't want to use it that way.

*index.html*:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="tr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body class="theme-dark">
    <app>Loading...</app>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*MainLayout.razor*:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<div class="grid-wrapper sidebar-bg bg1">
    <div id="theme-tab">
        <div class="theme-tab-item switch-theme bg-white" @onclick="ToggleTheme" data-theme="theme-default" title="Light"></div>
        <div class="theme-tab-item switch-theme bg-dark" @onclick="ToggleTheme" data-theme="theme-dark" title="Dark"></div>
    </div>
    <NavMenu />
    <SideBar />
    <div class="main">
        @Body
    </div>
    <Footer />
</div>

@code {
    private bool isDark = true;
    private string currentTheme => isDark ? "theme-dark" : "theme-default"; //I want to use this variable in other pages.

    private void ToggleTheme()
    {
        isDark = !isDark;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you want to change it in `<body>`, not `@body`.  `<body>` is not part of the Blazor Application and therefore can't be changed from within Blazor without some JSInterop.  Why do you not want to do it in the Layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change out the `<body>` class

Add a JS file.

*site.js*

```js
window.SetBodyCss = function (elementId, classname) {
    var link = document.getElementById(elementId);
    if (link !== undefined) {
        link.className = classname;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Reference it in *Host.cshtml*.
Create an `id` on `<body>`.

```html
<body id="BlazorMainBody">

    <script src="/site.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
```

Add a helper class

```
using Microsoft.JSInterop;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Blazor.Starter
{
    public class AppJsInterop
    {
        protected IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; }

        public AppJsInterop(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
        {
            JSRuntime = jsRuntime;
        }

        public ValueTask<bool> SetBodyCss(string elementId, string cssClass)
          => JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<bool>("SetBodyCss", elementId, cssClass);
    }
}
```

This shows toggling it in a page

```
<button type="button" @onclick="SetCss">SetCss</button>

@code {
    [Inject] private IJSRuntime _js { get; set; }

    private bool _isbodyCss;

    private string _bodyCss => _isbodyCss ? "Theme-Dark" : "Theme-Light";

    private async Task SetCss()
    {
        var appJsInterop = new AppJsInterop(_js);
        await appJsInterop.SetBodyCss("BlazorMainBody", _bodyCss);
        _isbodyCss = !_isbodyCss;
    }
}
```

You can change out the whole stylesheet in a similar way - see this [note of mine](https://shauncurtis.github.io/posts/DynamicCss.html)

Comment: I just didn't understand helper class part. I didn't add that part and it is working. Thanks for answer btw.

Comment: It was just a construct to hold the method.  Some people like to use helper classes.  You call it directly, no problem.  I normally do.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Layout HTML in a `<body>` tag.

I needed the `navbar-collapsed` class in the `<body>` in some layouts and `navbar-expand` in some layouts. By default it was `navbar-expand` so in the other layout where I needed collapsed I just wrapped my layout HTML in a `<body>` tag with `class="navbar-collapsed"` and it worked.

Comment: This is for Layouts in Blazor.

Comment: Ah! I see @Farrukh :)